# Is the truly actual type of error in Observable class of Rx really any?

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, observable

I'm trying to enforce more hard typed coding structure and the following intellisense info for an observable caught my curiosity.

> (method) Observable.subscribe(next?: (value: Response) => void, error?: (error: any) => void, complete?: () => void): Subscription (+2 overloads)

Now, I **do** understand what it says **but** I'm surprised why the `error` parameter is typed `any` and not something "real". I know that if I use it as `any`, there's `value` field and `requestId`.

Does it mean that the structure of the `error` instance in an observable are totally dependent on the server responding and can not be typed at all?

Comment: You can `throw` anything in JavaScript. It's not to do with the server, it's because in the generic `Observable<T>` you can't assume anything about the error.

Answer (score -4, accepted):

`Observable` is a generic class, [`Observable<T>`](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/src/Observable.ts#L28). The version of the [`.subscribe`](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/src/Observable.ts#L78) method you're calling takes up to three arguments:

```ts
subscribe(next?: (value: T) => void, error?: (error: any) => void, complete?: () => void): Subscription;
```

Note that only the first callback, `next`, uses the generic type `T` in its definition. This is because you can `throw` anything in JavaScript, so the generic version cannot make assumptions about what the `error` callback might receive.

The only way to get more specific types for the error would have been to make an `Observable<T, E>` with `error?: (error: E) => void`.